# Difference between two statements/quantifiers?

Tags: quantifiers

1) $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, if $a + \varepsilon > b$, then $a > b$.

2) If $\forall \varepsilon > 0, a + \varepsilon > b$, then $a > b$.

When I read these two statements, they seem to imply the exact same thing, but apparently they mean two different things. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in what it takes to prove or disprove the statements.

In the first example, to prove that the statement is false
you need merely find *one* value of $\varepsilon$ such that
$\varepsilon > 0$ is true but  $a + \varepsilon > b \Rightarrow a > b$ is false.
In the second example,
to prove the statement is true it is sufficient that for any $a$ and $b$
you can show either that $a > b$ or that there is some $\varepsilon$
such that $\varepsilon > 0$ is true but  $a + \varepsilon > b$ is false.

One thing that is not shown in these somewhat informal statements is how
you quantify $a$ and $b$. Since these are not formally quantified, we interpret
these statements as asserting something for all values of $a$ and $b$.
We can also be a lot more explicit about exactly what is the "if" part of the
implication and what is the "then" part of the implication by writing the
implication in the form $P \Rightarrow Q$ with parentheses to show exactly
where $P$ begins and ends.

1. $\forall a\colon \forall b\colon \forall \varepsilon > 0\colon (a + \varepsilon > b \Rightarrow a > b)$.
2. $\forall a\colon \forall b\colon (\forall \varepsilon > 0\colon a + \varepsilon > b) \Rightarrow a > b$.

It is easy to find a counterexample for the first statement; for example,
let $a = 1$, $b = 2$, and $\varepsilon = 9$.

We can use rules of formal logic to rewrite the second statement as follows:

$$\forall a\colon \forall b\colon (\neg(\forall \varepsilon > 0\colon a + \varepsilon > b) \vee (a > b)).$$
$$\forall a\colon \forall b\colon ((a \leq b) \Rightarrow \neg(\forall \varepsilon > 0\colon a + \varepsilon > b).$$
$$\forall a\colon \forall b\colon ((a \leq b) \Rightarrow (\exists \varepsilon > 0\colon a + \varepsilon \leq b).$$

We can now use the example $a = b = 1$ to prove the statement is false:
$1 \leq 1$, but $\forall \varepsilon > 0\colon 1 + \varepsilon > 1$.

But suppose we change the statements very slightly:

3. $\forall a\colon \forall b\colon \forall \varepsilon > 0\colon (a + \varepsilon > b \Rightarrow a \geq b)$.
4. $\forall a\colon \forall b\colon (\forall \varepsilon > 0\colon a + \varepsilon > b) \Rightarrow a \geq b$.

Statement 3 is (still) false, but statement 4 is true,
because if $a < b$ then there is some $\varepsilon > 0$
such that $a + \varepsilon \leq b$.

Answer (score 2):

What's being said in $1)$ is that: taken any positive real number $\epsilon$, if we have two real numbers $a$ and $b$ for which: $a + \epsilon > b$, then we would have $a > b$. Here, the choice of $\epsilon$ is prior to the choice of $a$ and $b$. The statement $a + \epsilon > b$ here does not hold for any positive $\epsilon$, it just holds for the one we have already chosen before.

While $2)$ says that: If we have two real numbers $a$ and $b$, such that taken any positive real number $\epsilon$, we have $a + \epsilon > b$, then $a > b$. Here, we already have the two real numbers $a$ and $b$, and the statement $a + \epsilon > b$ holds for any $\epsilon > 0$ we would like to choose.

Comment: In the second statement, take the example $a = b = 1$. Then $a > b$ is certainly false. Is $\forall \varepsilon > 0, a + \varepsilon > b$ also false?

Comment: Not. That should be $a \ge b$. Thanks @DavidK.